# debug/run executable fails with: this program is blocked by group policy

Tags: windows, exe, group-policy

I'm developing a Cpp application in MS VS on Win7 64bit, when I attempt to run/debug from the IDE, or from the command line, it fails to execute with this error:

"this program is blocked by group policy. for more information, contact your system administrator."

Btw, the exe is named Client.exe.

I attempted to resolve the issue via group policies, however non of the possible solutions posted here or elsewhere worked...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the answer for this particular issue, so I will post it here to save anybody in my situation some time.

The issue seems to be with the name of the executable. Apparently Client.exe will get blocked. Perhaps someone with deeper knowledge can provide a better solution, but my solution was to rename the output executable. Hope this answer is helpful.